# angularjs bootstrap tabs using

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I want to achieve bootstrap tabs like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/QPbCS/) example,
using [angularjs bootstrap](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.x/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.js) - It contains directives tabbable and tabPane.
It doesn't work, i have no idea how to get the ball rolling.

```
<tabbable>
    <tabPane title="first">
        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"></div>
    </tabPane>
    <tabPane title="tabbable">
        <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl"></div>
    </tabPane>
</tabbable>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('orders_manage', ['orders_manage.services', 'bootstrap'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/first', { templateUrl:'/partials/first.html', controller:FirstCtrl})
    .when('/second', { templateUrl:'/partials/second.html', controller:SecondCtrl})
```

Comment: Here is the version from jsFiddle updated to 1.0.1: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/HaN7d/1/ it works fine. I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to do: make the version from the fiddle work? Or the one from angular work? If you are after making the angular one working, what is the problem you are facing? Could you send a jsFiddle exposing the problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the source you'll find that these directives are restricted to class names: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.x/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.js#L54

Rewriting your example to use `<div class="tabbable">` and `<div class="tab-pane">` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PjuAWn?p=preview) shows an example of what you are looking for.  Original link found on the [angularjs JsFiddle-Examples wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples) .

> Angular Bootstrap Tabbable with ng-view and url as current tab deep
>   linking (Andy Joslin)

Also, depending on your use case, you may want to take a look at the **Create Components** section on the angularjs home page http://angularjs.org . The **'component.js'** source code in that section shows example code to quickly get tabs working without [angularjs bootstrap](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.x/src/bootstrap/bootstrap.js).  You can use this example to build a custom solution if you need more control over the functionality.